# I can't understand why I'm getting this SwiftUI Environment Object Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, environmentobject

So I'm trying to update one property of an `@EnvironmentObject`. I keep getting this error:

```
SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:90: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

My code looks like this:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIHostingController<HomeView> {
    
    // MARK: - Public Properties

    var topThreePublicUsers = PassthroughSubject<[ExternalUser], Never>()

    
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    
    // MARK: - Initializer
    
    init() {
        super.init(rootView: HomeView())

        _ = rootView.environmentObject(HomeView.ViewModel())

        topThreePublicUsers
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.viewModel.topThreePublicUsers, on: rootView)
            .store(in:&cancellables)
    }
    
    @MainActor required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func pushPublicLeaderBoard(viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let viewController = viewController as? UIHostingController<PublicLeaderboardView> {
            rootView.viewModel.publicLeaderboard = viewController.rootView
        }
    }

}
```

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Environment
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    
    // MARK: - View Model
    
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var profileView: ProfileView?
    }
      
    
    // MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        viewModel.profileView
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I just can't access the environment externally but I don't know... lil help?

Comment: After more carefully reading your code, I noticed that what you are doing is *very* against the principles of SwiftUI, and that this is a giant [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What on earth is this `ViewModel`? You shouldn't have your own view models in SwiftUI in the first place, but let's ignore that for a second, why does it have `View`s as its properties? In fact, `View`s themselves *is already* a "view model". You don't technically make any "views" yourself. SwiftUI does that for you.

Comment: From what I can see, your entire architecture is really weird. You seem to be wrapping *every* view you have in a `UIHostingController`, like there is also `UIHostingController<PublicLeaderboardView>`, and then assigning the SwiftUI views in those to your view model!? What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: The architecture is based on `https://github.com/uber/RIBs` but essentially I don't want the `View` to drive the UI. There's another object that owns the `UIHostingController`. 

Currently, I do this instead:
`@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()`. It works but I liked the `@EnvironmentObject` way.

Comment: @Sweeper Is right the View struct already is the view model and SwiftUI makes the real views for you automatically. If you try to use objects instead you are basically trying to reimplement what SwiftUI already does.

Comment: Never hold views in variables that aren’t view builders. But you should be injecting into the home view not the root view you can also just use a StateObject instead you aren’t using the view model in UIKit

Comment: @malhal I understand that there's an established design pattern with SwiftUI. That design pattern does not suit my needs so I needed to try something else. What I'm looking for here is to be able to supply the view that I want to transition to at the moment I want to transition. I don't think that's possible with `@EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: @WikipediaBrown you just supply the View struct which is a description of what you want and SwiftUI will make the actual view at the right moment you want to transition

Comment: @malhal I need to keep a reference to the view in another object so I can't create it on the fly.

Comment: View structs are values they cannot be referenced

Comment: @malhal I'm currently following this pattern with success in production but I wanted to use the `@EnvironmentObject` instead of investing view models at creation.

Comment: EnvironmentObject is usually for holding model data not view data

Comment: I understand that there’s existing paradigms around use that exist, I just wanted to use this for dependency injection instead of the initializer.